# AppleScript : get contextual menu of a window

Tags: macos, menu, applescript, right-click

I need to script with applescript the equivalent of right-clicking inside a window of an app and selecting an option in the contextual menu.
Here's the code I'm using, inspired by some code I found in another thread :

```
  tell application targetApp to activate
  delay 0.2
  tell application "System Events"
    tell process targetApp

       tell window 1 to perform action "AXShowMenu"
       delay 0.2
       keystroke "Open"
       keystroke return

     end tell
  end tell
```

I don't get any compiler nor execution error, but nothing happens, as if no contextual menu option has been selected.

Any idea of what I missed ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: RE: "`targetApp`" --  What _application_ is it?  RE: "Any idea of what I missed ?"  --  Yes that fact that whichever _application_ is defined as `targetApp` its `window ` may not have that _action_ programmed in to it. For example, if the target _application_ was **TextEdit**, then its `window 1` would open the _context menu_, but of course `keystroke "Open"` would just type it into the _window_. Now if it's **Finder**, then `tell toolbar 1 of window 1 to perform action "AXShowMenu"` would show its _context menu_. Every _application_ may/can/will be different, it's not necessarily universal.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So far, the target app is Google Chrome. Where can I find the doc saying if that action is programmed into it ?

Comment: RE: "Where can I find the doc saying if that action is programmed into it ?" -- LOL If there is a _list_ anywhere, I have no idea where it would be. I use **Accessibility Inspector**, a part of **Xcode**, to examine the given properties of an _object_. For example, with a _window_ in **Google Chrome**, the first **UI Element** that reports having an _action_ of `AXShowMenu`, the following _command_ will show it once **Google Chrome** is _activated_: `tell radio button 1 of tab group 1 of group 1 of window 1 to perform action "AXShowMenu"`

Comment: Another example is to query for its `actions`, e.g. `tell application "System Events" to return actions of window 1 of process "Google Chrome"` **returns** `{action "AXRaise" of window "New Tab - Google Chrome" of application process "Google Chrome"}`